# How to host explorer context menu in app?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharpshell

I have been developing an app with SharpShell Context menu handler that adds and removes certain functions to the explorer context menu. I am trying to create an interface so that the user can choose what to add depending on what is currently available but i cannot figure out how to display the native explorer context menu in the UI. The app is written in VB.net but i can translate C#. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over Windows Registry to get existing items and need to update these registry keys to update the menu item.

Following registry keys are available:

1. When you right click in blank area a folder: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`
2. Look for `shell` folder under your file extension registry to add open with programs.
3. Look for `ContextMenuHandlers`

Check this [guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens) on CodeProject.

Check this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776820(VS.85).aspx) on Microsoft.

C# wrapper is also [available](http://chestermr.blogspot.sg/2007/03/shell-extension-context-menu.html)